# Diferencias entre las formas de acceder a un atributo de instancia en Python

Tags: python

Bien, en el siguiente codigo de ejemplo ...

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = 'Hola'

persona_nueva = Persona()
```

Cual seria la diferencia entre acceder al atributo nombre a traves de la *dot notation* (`persona_nueva.nombre`) y acceder directamente al diccionario de sus atributos (`persona_nueva.__dict__['nombre']`)

Supongo que en el primer caso se estara siguiendo el *protocolo descriptor* (el interprete no va a buscar el atributo al diccionario del objeto sino al de la clase para comprobar la existencia de algun descriptor ), y en el segundo simplemente se esta accediendo directamente a los atributos, no?. Esto lo supongo ya que si se emplea la *dot notation* en un descriptor, se hacen llamadas recursivas al descriptor continuamente ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
class DescriptorNombre:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls) -> str:
        print(f'Retornando el nombre del objeto intancia de la clase {obj.__class__.__name__}')
        return obj.__dict__['nombre']
    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
        print(f'Modificando el nombre del objeto intancia de la clase {obj.__class__.__name__}')
        obj.__dict__['nombre'] = value
    def __delete__(self, obj) -> None:
        print(f'ELiminando el nombre del objeto intancia de la clase {obj.__class__.__name__}')
        del obj.nombre

class Persona:
    nombre = DescriptorNombre()
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre


persona_nueva = Persona('Santiago')
print(persona_nueva.nombre)
persona_nueva.nombre = 'Nelson'
del persona_nueva.nombre
```

-(Notese el `RecursionError` en el ejemplo anterior) En cambio si se accede directamente al atributo (en el dunder `__delete__` del descriptor) ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
class DescriptorNombre:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls) -> str:
        print(f'Retornando el nombre del objeto intancia de la clase {obj.__class__.__name__}\n')
        return obj.__dict__['nombre']
    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
        print(f'Modificando el nombre del objeto intancia de la clase {obj.__class__.__name__}\n')
        obj.__dict__['nombre'] = value
    def __delete__(self, obj) -> None:
        print(f'ELiminando el nombre del objeto intancia de la clase {obj.__class__.__name__}\n')
        del obj.__dict__['nombre']

class Persona:
    nombre = DescriptorNombre()
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre


persona_nueva = Persona('Santiago')
print(persona_nueva.nombre)
persona_nueva.nombre = 'Nelson'
del persona_nueva.nombre
```

-En el segundo ejemplo no lanza el `RecursionError` dado que no estamos siguiendo el *protocolo descriptor* (es decir, no le estamos indicando al interprete que queremos que vaya a la clase `persona` a buscar un descriptor). Con lo cual, finalmente la pregunta seria: *es cierta mi suposicion??, la diferencia entre estas dos formas es el seguimiento (y no seguimiento) del **protocolo descriptor**?*

Comment: puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) y también [esto](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

Comment: La única razón para acceder vía diccionario es que el nombre del atributo esté en una variable. Si conoces el nombre, objeto.atributo es lo mismo pero más corto.

Comment: Tus dos ejemplos son exactamente iguales. Acualízalos, por favor, que elaboraré una explicación cuando tenga un tiempo.

Comment: @revliscano no, son completamente diferentes, no se si te habras dado cuenta que en el primer ejemplo lanza un RecursionError y en el segundo no ...

Comment: @PySanti estas haciendo el mismo procedimiento y nunca usas la notación `class.__dict__['atrr']`

Comment: @Christian mira el __delete__ de los descriptores

Comment: @PySanti lo siento no me había dado cuenta :)

Comment: @Christian no hay problema, igualmente lo edite, quizas no estaba tan claro ...